# Having trouble with my menu on mac Safari. Works fine on Windows Safari

Tags: html, css, xhtml

http://wilwaldon.com/itsbroken/stay.html

If you could take a look and tell me if it works in Safari that would be awesome. A screenshot would help if you find a bug. According to Adobe Browser Lab it looks fine, but according to my friend with a mac it's all sorts of messed up (the second tier's messed up, the vertical lines after the links look offset about 7px lower than the menu).

And supposedly it works fine offline, but not when viewed on a live server. There's something fishy.

Comment: This belongs on http://doctype.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, Safari 4.0.4 and WebKit r52951 on Mac OS X 10.6.2.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I guess it works locally or on certain servers. I'm trying to pinpoint it right now and since I don't have a mac I'm trying to get some help.